# How to connecting to other database and not changing global variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two databases, primary and secondary.
on the same page I need to take the data from second base, but without losing the connection to the first base.

Comment: Are you using PDO or mysqli?

Comment: Maybe you should not use global variables at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make multiple calls to mysql_connect(), but if the parameters are the same you need to pass true for the '$new_link' (fourth) parameter, otherwise the same connection is reused.

so then you have

```
$dbh1 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 
$dbh2 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, true);


mysql_select_db('database1', $dbh1);
mysql_select_db('database2', $dbh2);
```

Then to query database 1, do this:

```
mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh1);
```

and for database 2:

```
mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh2);
```

Comment: you really should not recommend the usage of mysql_* functions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: I know, it's just that I still need to get used to it, and this was just an example.